# gcc: Using a function from another directory

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I would like to use a function from another directory. So I put this line on the top,

```
#include "~/ffmpeg/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h"
```

and ran

```
 gcc filename.c
```

and getting this error

```
error: avcodec.h: No such file or directory
```

The spelling is correct and the file exists. Why does the compiler think the file does not exist?

Comment: how about using absolute path for testing whether the file can be found?

Comment: None of this is calling any functions. You are including a file. That's all. :)

Comment: Please, do not post "follow-up" questions as edits. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#include <avcodec.h>    /* NOT "avcodec.h" */
```

Then:

```
gcc -I/include/file/path/where/avcodec.h/lives
```

If you use `-I`, use the angle-brackets, if you want to include based on a path relative to the file containing the `#include`, use the quotes.

I would use:

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
```

and:

```
$ gcc -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include ...
```

Comment: #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>works like a charm! Did not give me any error!

Comment: Great! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "~/ffmpeg/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h"
```

Is using ~ which is a HOME identification for KSH and BASH only.
You need to use a full/relative path as include.

Answer (score 0):

A preferred way to do this - which makes it so that code doesn't have to change simply because a header is in a different directory, is to place in the code:

```
#include <avcodec.h>
```

Then when you are compiling add the switch -I

```
gcc -I/home/<username>/ffmpeg/include/libavcodec
```

Its best to use the full path to the header.

Comment: Following this gave me this. error: avcodec.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell gcc where the include directory is using -I and where the shared libraries are with -L

`gcc -I~/ffmpeg/include -L~/ffmpeg/lib filename.c`

an change the include to

`#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"`

Comment: It should be noted that that is a capital `I` rather than an "l"

Comment: This gave me: error: libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory